# how to manage an R program where the functions are stored in different source files

Tags: r

I finally arrived at a point in using R where my programs are not anymore grown-up command line scripts, but real codes. At this point, I think it doesn't make sense to keep all the functions used by the main code in the same source file. Now, If I understand correctly, the way to use function `myfunction`, stored in file `hereliesfunction.r`, from a script stored in file `myscript.r`, is to add the line

```
source("hereliesfunction.r")
```

in file `myscript.r`, before the part of the script code where `myfunction` is used.

1. Is this the right approach in R?
2. Do I need a different source command for each function used by my main code? I guess it works "recursively",i.e., I can put `source` commands in
   `hereliesfunction.r` to let `myfunction` use other functions.
3. What happens when I return from `myfunction`?  Do these other
   functions remain in memory, ready to be accessed by the main code too, or are they destroyed just like any other object created by `myfunction`?
4. Finally, is there some guideline on whether to store all the
   functions used by a main code in the same directory as the main
   code, or not?

Comment: Another option would be to create a package with all the custom functions you need and then just load that package inside `myscript.R`.

Comment: @docendodiscimus, thanks for the tip. I don't know how to create a package. I had a look at [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf) and it looks interesting, but it also seems a bit more complex than what I was looking for. However, if that's the standard approach in R, I'll try to study it.

Comment: Take a look at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/. In the beginning it's a bit more complicated than just using scripts, but it's worth learning it

Answer (score 2):

Once you `source` a R file, it runs all the commands in that file. If it contains a function definition, it stores it into the global environment and is at your disposal until you remove it or close R session (so 3., yes).

Your entire post is *screaming* R package. As @docendodiscimus has pointed out, you should invest some time to develop a package. Not only does it hold your code in one place, is easy to maintain, it also offers a great platform to document your code (probably the most important part of code development/analysis) through help files and vignettes and offers easy version control through local and remote repositories (git, svn...).

Comment: I like your answer (and also the other one...it's hard to choose!!!). I have a doubt, though: one of the things that makes me unsure about using packages, is that I have some utility  functions which I want to reuse in different projects (main codes + functions + data). If I make a package for each project , I end up having different copies of the same utility function in different packages, and that's terrible! That's why I'd rather have a folder with all my utility functions, and in each main code `source` only those I need, instead than all of them. What do you think?

Comment: Of course, I could also create an `utilfuns` package to hold all of them. However, now each main which wants to use one or more of them, has to `library` the whole package, thus needlessly polluting the namespace (I guess it's called environment in R?). Instead, sourcing only the functions I need from a common storage folder doesn't have this issue (it does have issues of portability across different machines, but that's not a requirement).

Answer (score 1):

- [about sourcing] Is this the right approach in R?

Yes but in the mid-term, consider building a package as stated by @docendo discimus. `devtools::create()` and if you use RStudio `Projects > New package` are your friends. Learning to build packages is made simple by Hadley's R-pkg and was, personally, the best investment ever in R. Plus documenting and writing tutorials/vignettes and writing tests is always useful: it may be time consuming at the first glance, but you will probably soon hugely benefit from it (better understanding of your code, realizing you can improve the package architecture, etc.)

- Do I need a different source command for each function used by my main code?

All functions, and in a larger extent code, located in the file sourced will be executed in R (so functions will be declared and available, you can check it with `ls()`

- I guess it work "recursively",i.e., I can put source commands in hereliesfunction.r to let myfunction use other functions.

Yes

- What happens when I return from myfunction? Do these other functions remain in memory, ready to be accessed by the main code too, or are they destroyed just like any other object created by myfunction?

Not sure to understand but may be related to previous points.

- Finally, is there some guideline on whether to store all the functions used by a main code in the same directory as the main code, or not?

You can store them wherever you want, as long as the path for `source` is the right one. But it's generally a better practice to store all your functions in the same directory (or in a subfolder, eg `/code`, so that you just change your working directory once (or if you use RStudio's projects, you don't even need to bother, you just open the project), and as a side effect, as long as one is working in the same directory, the relative paths will still work. And thus you can share the folder with Dropbox or other, which ease collaboration.

Again, in the mid term or if many projects use the same source files, it's probably a good idea to write a package (for your own use, or to share on GitHub or CRAN or...)